# python how to programmatically get line number of class definition

Tags: python

suppose I have a module named test.py. 
In this file, I know a class named dummy.
How to get the line number of class dummy definition after I import it?

Is there an API can do such thing?

if dummy is a function, then `dummy.__code__.co_firstlineno` will return the line no. But if dummy is a class, it doesn't have`__code__`attribute

I wanna know is there a way which can return the line no without parsing the file.

Comment: Possibly an xy question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve, Why do you need to know the line no?

Comment: Can't use just parse your `test.py` file for `class Dummy`?

Comment: Just curiosity. if dummy is a function, then`dummy.__code__.co_firstlineno` will return the line no. But if dummy is a class, it doesn't have `__code__ `attribute.

Comment: The methods of the class have a `__code__` attribute so you could find roughly the line number by checking each of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inspect.findsource(test.dummy)[1]` provides the line number via regex search in the source file (rather slow).

If you define the class, line numbers could be exposed like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def test_01(self):
        assert 1
    _classline_ = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_firstlineno
    _thisline_ = inspect.currentframe().f_lineno
```

---

Update 2020 / Python 3.9+ : `inspect.findsource` now uses (slow) `ast` instead of regex. (bpo-35113 / [commit 696136b9](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/696136b993e11b37c4f34d729a0375e5ad544ade))

Comment: `inspect.findsource()` **does not use regexes to find class declarations.** Instead, it actually fully parses the module declaring that class into its Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) representation and then iteratively searches that tree for a node declaring that class courtesy the standard `ast` module. On the bright side, this is failproof. On the dark side, this is so absurdly slow that you should *never, ever* do this in performance-critical code. The `ast` module makes regex-based parsing look like Hermes, the Greek winged shoe god.

Comment: @CecilCurry  (slow) ast usage was introduced recently (bpo-35113 / 696136b9). Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [Retrieving source code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code) section of `inspect`. Try `getsourcefile()` and `getsourcelines()`.

Answer (score 1):

This requires static analysis code I wrote for the `xdoctest` module. I'm not sure it solves 100% of the cases, but I think it is more robust than a regex search.

```
def static_calldefs(modpath):
    from xdoctest import static_analysis as static
    calldefs = dict(static.parse_calldefs(fpath=modpath))
    return calldefs

def get_object_lineno(obj):
    try:
        # functions just 
        lineno = obj.__code__.co_firstlineno
    except AttributeError:
        attrname = obj.__name__
        modpath = sys.modules[obj.__module__].__file__
        calldefs = static_calldefs(modpath)
        ub.modpath_to_modname(modpath)
        calldef = calldefs[attrname]
        lineno = calldef.lineno
    return lineno
```